# Guest session in shop online, cart in NodeJS/AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, passport.js

How could I make sessions for guests on my site so that after accessing they can do shopping on it, and the whole cart is saved into the session?

At this moment I use Node.js with Passport and AngularJS.

Comment: Jabloñski, I edited the question in order to make it somehow easier to read and understand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess one strategy can be :

- If you are a guest, store the session data in localStorage or cookies.
- When a user logs in, it clears the session in localStorage (eventually replacing it with some session data from the database)
- Eventually, when a guest sign up, you can transfer the guest session data to the new user.

This is simple and only affect your Front-End part (except for third part but it not a must have), but the guest session is lost each time someone logs in, also you don't have much control on what is in the session data (better don't have anything sensitive).

Another, more complicated one can be :

- Create session storage in you back which are only used for guest session data.
- Store in cookies a guest session ID.
- When there is a guest session ID, you can retrieve from your guest session store some data.
- If someone is logs in, just ignore the guest session ID from cookies.

This solves the problem of the log in = lost of session but there is some serious work on back-end part.

Finally, instead of the back end guest session storage and ID system, you can simply store all the data in a "guest cookie" and ignore it too, it depends on how much control you want on the session data.

Comment: Ok how to do that i would have guest sessions?? Can u tell me ?:)

Comment: I guess just do like you do for logged in users. Keep track of wether the user is logged in or not, and if not, keep track of the data.
For logged user, you keep the session in RAM or in a Redis store. Passport works with middleware, ie each time you make a http request, it will be used to see wich user has made the request if there is one. For that, it is checking with a cookie (connect.sid). You can create your own middleware if you want guest data in server cache, or juste simply put it in localStorage directly. If the user use the same computer and browser, data will remain there.